What Stack Exchange site should I use for asking "best way to do something" in a programming language?
I have a question about the best or standard way to go about something in Godot.  Typically, I use Stack Overflow for programming questions, but SO is specifically for questions where you have code that's not working and need someone to fix it.  My question is more open-ended than that.
Just in case more context is needed to answer this meta question, the question I want to pose is regarding the best or standard way to use a tile map/tile set where tiles each have scripts attached to them, but also have animations and alternatives and so a TileSetAtlasSource is preferable to a TileSetScenesCollectionSource.

I have looked at Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?, and have, in fact, used that question several times before, but in this case, it does not answer my question.  Stack Overflow is the closest, but, as I said, I don't have broken code.

Probably there is no site that would take such an opinion based question. Best is generally a terribly subjective thing.

"Best" and "standard" are concepts that are quite far apart. If you can define either properly, the suggested duplicate will likely still answer your question.

A simpler version of the post linked in the comment above. If your question is about "optimal" I'd go for Code Review (and specify what you're looking to improve on the existing solution), if it's about something broader like "design pattern" I'd try Software Engineering. Now, I have seen SO questions about "optimal" or "optimized" ended up being well received, although it's difficult to find a meta post that legitimizes that - it depends if the question can be objectively answered or will attract opinions.

I think none of them. While I (obviously) don't know the standards for all 183 sites in the network, I think this is probably too opinion-based. "What is the best way" is generally a matter of opinion.

I'd suggest reworking the question so that you're asking about a specific dimension of "best" (fastest, least memory, shortest) and asking on Stack Overflow (which is not just about debugging existing code).
Alternatively, Code Review would give you suggestions on how to improve your working code, and maybe even more effective approaches.
